# session not being unset or destroyed

Tags: php

***session_start() is called in connect.php but is not included here for security reasons***

I am having trouble with a session not being unset or destroyed

I have a logout.php where i handle the logging out and it looks like this

```html
<?
 if(isset($_POST['logout'])){
  session_start();
  session_unset();
  session_destroy();
  header("Location: index.php");
 }
?>
```

I then call this code in my navigation which is working fine however once i log in and try to log out the navigation should go away and the forms should be displayed but the navigation is the only thing being display here is that script

```html
<nav>
<?
 if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
  include("server/constants/nav.php");
 } else{?>
  <div class="form">
  <input type="button" id="displayLoginForm" onclick="showLogin()" value="Login">
  <input type="button" id="displayRegisterForm" onclick="showRegister()" value="Register">
   <div id="loginSection" style="display:none">
  <?  include("server/display/LoginForm.php") ?>
   </div>

   <div id="registerSection" style="display:none">
   <?  include("server/display/RegisterForm.php") ?>
   </div>
  </div>
<? } ?>
</nav>
```

**Other relevant scripts**

HandleLogin.php

```html
<?
 if(isset($_POST['Login'])){
  $user = $_POST['username'];
  $pass = $_POST['password'];

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM energywise WHERE username='$user'";
  $query = mysql_query($sql);
  $row = mysql_fetch_object($query);

  $id = htmlspecialchars($row->id);
  $firstName = htmlspecialchars($row->firstname);
  $lastName = htmlspecialchars($row->lastname);
  $username = htmlspecialchars($row->username);
  $password = htmlspecialchars($row->password);
  $mail = htmlspecialchars($row->email);

  if(empty($id)){
   echo 'Account does not exist';
  } elseif($pass != $password){
   echo 'Passwords do not match';
  } else{
   $_SESSION['user'] = $id;
   header("Location: index.php");
  }
 }
?>
```

nav.php

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navigation.css">
<script src="js/nav.js"></script>

<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='index.php'>Home</a></li>
   <li><a href='calender.php'>Calender</a></li>
   <li><a href='locations.php'>Locations</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Placeholder</a></li>

   <form method="post">
   <li><input type="submit" name="logout" value="Logout"></li>
   </form>
</ul>
```

Comment: You're not calling `session_start()` in HandleLogin.php

Comment: session unset is fine here i believe, you aren't using session_start(); while setting up your user_id into session..

Comment: session_start() is called in connect.php

Comment: you should remove this line `session_start();` from your logout action. And add session_start(), on HandleLogin.php, before you set the user id `$_SESSION['user'] = $id;`

Comment: is your connect.php called when logout.php is executed?

Comment: connect.php is at the top of every page

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't know, but did you test if `logout.php` is being accessed? I miss `action="logout.php"` on the form:

```
<form action="logout.php" method="post">
<li><input type="submit" name="logout" value="Logout"></li>
</form>
```

Comment: that was it :) thanks

Comment: @JoséphFlames no problem, it happens :)

Comment: could use help http://stackoverflow.com/q/35641099/5491906